# Aside from sell or admire it, what can one do with an NFT?

Tags: nft

My understanding of NFT's is *very* basic - limited to a couple of short youtube explainers and a basic understanding of decentralised trust systems (e.g. blockchains).

I understand that someone with an NFT may **sell** it, thus producing a positive cash transfer.

I also understand that someone who owns an NFT may **admire** it, in the same way someone may admire art, software, a pet, a story, etc.

#### Question

Other than being sold or admired, can NFTs do anything else, practical or otherwise?

#### The little I know so far

I've heard that NFTs can be used as a sort of license over characters from stories or art works, but I do not know of any legal system would actually enforce such a licence, hence I'm not sure that aspect offers value?

Comment: Yes, there are games that use NFTs for the characters, cards, properties, etc.

Answer (score 2):

#### Metaverse objects

I know a few projects including a couple we work on that build "[Rich NFT](https://ethora.com/wiki/Rich_NFTs_(Metaverse_ready))s" or "Metaverse NFTs" where basically a 3D model is included allowing to use it in 3D spaces such as Decentraland, Spatial etc. **Game items** are being traded as blockchain tokens / NFTs for quite a while already (see DMarket and other similar platforms - they've been around for years).

#### Real Estate

There are projects that link NFTs to **real-world property** akin to security tokens. Here are couple of publications that talk about that but no specific details:

- https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/top-5-real-world-non-fungible-tokens-use-cases-946d92591fbf
- https://bccollective.io/can-nft-be-use-for-real-world-assets/

Of course if you include **Digital / Metaverse land** under Real Estate then you get more examples such as notorious Decentraland, Cryptovoxels, PolkaCity, Superworld, Upland, [Area](https://area.world/) etc.

#### Collateral

NFTs can also be used as a **collateral** in DeFi transactions.

#### Certificates, Licenses and Tickets

Easier to combat counterfeit certifications and licenses if they are issued as NFTs so the issuer, the origin, total amount issued etc can be easily verified with a couple clicks on blockchain explorer. NFTs also start to be used as a medium for [tickets to sports shows](https://www.ledgerinsights.com/nfl-launches-league-wide-nft-tickets-with-ticketmaster/).

#### Origin tracking / digital copy

Take a photo of a particular organic tomato vine and include it as NFT along with the product itself. You may also transact this NFT between the wallets of supply chain members (farm -> warehouse -> distributor -> supermarket). Great way to track the [provenance](https://www.dappros.com/201901/provenance-tracking-origin-via-blockchain/) of an item in the supply chain.

#### Collectibles (digital and physical)

See the [RWANFT](https://rwanft.io/) (Real World Assets NFT) and Matterium protocol. They have come up with the concept combining Asset Passports, Automated Custodians and Smart Property Register. They claim to be a universal file format for "uploading physical goods to the Internet".

So far it seems they have succeeded on that with their Captain Kirk figures collection :)

---

Now, you're right selling and admiring are the main "applications" today but it's a smart contract supported by a distributed ledger and a lot can be done with it. We'll definitely see more applications going forward.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).